# .NET Core 2.2 with Angular 12 - Site does not load until I cause a recompilation

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, .net-core, single-page-application

We have a website that is built on .NET Core 2.2 and Angular 8. I have been migrating it to Angular 12 and the site now all works correctly with just one strange issue. When I run the site initially it will never work until I go and save a file in the angular project causing it to re-compile.

If I just run it then the site will load for 50 seconds then display `The Angular CLI process did not start listening for requests within the timeout period of 50 seconds`. However I can see that the site has compiled successfully after just ~7 seconds in the Output window.

In Startup.ConfigureServices()

```
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
   configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
});
```

In Startup.Configure()

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
     {
       spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = ConfigDefaults.DefaultStaticFileOptions;
       spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

       if (env.IsDevelopment())
       {
          spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
       }
     });
```

If I go into any typescript file and save it then it recompiles and then if I refresh the page works just fine.

Is there anything additional required to make this work correctly with angular 12?

Comment: This usually happens when upgrading. Have you already tried the following? Remove `node_modules` folder - Remove `package-lock.json` - Remove `bin` and `obj` folders - Run `npm install` again. Usually this fixes it for me

Comment: @Pieterjan I didn't exactly upgrade the project, I actually deleted and recreated the ClientApp by using ng new and copying over what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking [the code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/6350af9620165d6a1d65c7f3ce789a7909e95b1b/src/Middleware/Spa/SpaServices.Extensions/src/AngularCli/AngularCliMiddleware.cs#L82) it seems that the `UseAngularCliServer` ends up waiting for the text "open your browser on http..." to appear on stdout to determine the angular site is ready. For some reason though it seems that this line is being output to the error stream instead of the standard output stream for me. I assume this is related to the fact I have some sass warnings output during the build.

I added a new script to my `package.json` to redirect the error stream to stdout: `"start:asp": "powershell ng serve 2>&1",` and updated `Startup.cs` to use this script `spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start:asp");` and now it seems to load correctly on startup.

I think this is an issue with the middleware rather than angular as when I run `ng serve` manually this line goes to the correct stream.

**Update**

I found after upgrading to .NET 5 the issue seemed to stop so I guess this is an issue with this combination of angular and .NET. The above workaround seems to help but doesn't solve it completely.